# Plus sign in front of positive number in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that has both negative and positive numbers, the negative numbers already have the negative sign in front of them, what I am looking for is how to add a positive(plus) sign in front of the positive numbers in the one column? The column name is called `Position Change`
The dataframe changes all the time so I do not want to manually enter the plus sign.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried any code yet as I am not sure how to implement so it is done automatically with numbers in a column.

Answer (score 3):

You could use pandas style and formatting:

```
df.style.format({'numbers':"{0:+g}"})
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':np.arange(-10,5)})
df.style.format({'numbers':"{0:+g}"})
```

Output:

[image]

Update to answer comment.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':np.arange(-10,5), 'othernumbers':np.arange(-10,5)})

df.style.format({'numbers':"{0:+g}"})
```

[image]

Comment: My dataframe has multiple columns, how do I implement that to a single column called "Position Change" rather than all the columns? ?Also the positive and negative numbers are not in order in the rows, so for example I would have something like this - -1, 0, 2, -3, 0, 2, -1 etc . There are also some rows with 0 where there has been no change in position.

Comment: @MoodyRocket, that is exactly what that does with the dictionary in `format`.

Comment: sorry I edited my other question just as you responded.

Comment: I gave the above a try, but it did not do anything at all, I also did not get a error. Strange, not sure why it is not working.

Comment: @ScottBoston how do we achieve this but for numbers greater than zero?